# Почему перестает работать слайдер slick после перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

После перезагрузки slick перестает работать, пропадает блок slick-list и slick-track, после очистки кєша слайдер вновь работает, пока не перезагрузишь страницу, может у кого было такое?

Comment: при ресайзе окна тоже работает

Comment: http://keramika.cc.ua

Answer (score 0):

Всегда работаю со slick слайдером, но о такой проблеме слышу впервые. 
Сначала дам рядовые советы, вдруг что-то поможет.
1) Скачайте заново с официального сайта файлы и подключите всё по инструкции.
2) Создайте ещё один самый просто слайдер, просто для проверки его работоспособности. 
3) Проверьте консоль, может там что-то покажет.

Вы пробовали подключать его отдельно? Скажем на какой-нибудь платформе типа codepen? то есть возьмите полностью ваш html, css, js даже свои же файлы подключите и проверьте, будет ли он работать удалённо не на вашем сервере.

Comment: заменил файлы - не помогло, в консоле нет ошибок, слайдер нормально работает, при первой загрузке, при перезагрузке страницы перестает работать, помогает очистка кэша или ресайз страницы

Comment: Пробовали создать ещё один слайдер? Как вариант что-то в вёрстке или в js конфликтует.
И подскажите, какой именно слайде на сайте плохо работает?

Comment: если прописать всю структуру в html, то нормально работает, но данные считываются с файла JSON и через js выводятся в html, в результате при первой загрузке слайдер работает, а после перезагрузки перестает. Какие то данные записываются в кэш, после чего перестает работать слайдер, а когда его очищаешь, вновь слайдер работает, вот и спрашиваю может кто то сталкивался с такой проблемой

Comment: Вы через JSON оказывается всё прописали?! Вы должны были это указать в вопросе. Более обширно в следующий раз описывайте проблему, указывайте все нюансы.
C этим вообще не сталкивался. Могу лишь посоветовать прописать всё в html и не париться.

Answer (score 0):

`<телепатия>`

Вы сохраняете что-то в куки/`localStorage`/`sessionStorage`, а потом неправильно это считываете.

`</телепатия>`

Comment: в куки я не сохраняю ничего